# Liferay <aui:validator> for dates?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I'm trying to make a simple custom *aui:validator* for the birthday field on the registration form but it is simply not working. Any ideas?

```
<aui:input name="birthday" value="<%=birthday%>">
    <aui:validator name="custom" errorMessage="some-error">
        function (val, fieldNode, ruleValue) {
            return false;
        }
    </aui:validator>
</aui:input>
```

What I'd like to achieve is to check if the user is 18 years old at the registration.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to use Lucky Boy's solution either. For some mysterious reason it didn't work at the `create_account.jsp` file.

As a workaround I create a new exception in the header of the file:

```
<liferay-ui:error exception="<%=NotOldEnoughException.class%>"
    message="Not old enough" />
```

And made the checking in a hooked version of the `EditUserAction` file.

Comment: what problem you faced while implementing my solution?

Comment: To be honest, I'm completely unsure. I triple-checked the code. The thing is that neither Firebug nor Dragonfly indicated any jscript error regarding to your solution (I also saw the apporach in several other forums, so basically it should work). No exceptions in the Tomcat lots too. There must be some magic in the background for the `create_account.jsp` that messes up things. Or maybe I have some trivial error. Anyway, thanks for your time and if I find the issue, will turn back to this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Here i am validating that **selected date** is greater than **today's date**.You can change as per your need.

```
<script>
 AUI().ready('aui-form-validator', 'aui-overlay-context-panel', function(A) {

   A.mix(
        YUI.AUI.defaults.FormValidator.RULES,
        {
            dateCustomRule: function(val, fieldNode, ruleValue) {
                var val = new Date(Date.parse(val,"MMM dd yyyy"));
                var today=new Date();

                return (val>today);

            }
        },
        true
    );

    var validator2 = new A.FormValidator({
        boundingBox: document.<portlet:namespace/>form,

        fieldContainer: 'p',

        rules: {        
            <portlet:namespace />dueDate:{
                required: true,
                dateCustomRule:true
            }
        },
    fieldStrings: {

            <portlet:namespace />dueDate: {
                required: 'Due Date Required',
                dateCustomRule: 'Date must be greater than Today\'s Date'
            }

        },

        on: {
            validateField: function(event) {
            },

            validField: function(event) {
            },

            errorField: function(event) {
            },

            submitError: function(event) {
                var formEvent = event.validator.formEvent;
                var errors = event.validator.errors;

            },

            submit: function(event) {
                var formEvent = event.validator.formEvent;
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to make the validator would be something like this.

I hope it helps you,

```
                         <aui:validator name="custom"  errorMessage="Tienes que ser mayor de 18 años">
                                     function (val, fieldNode, ruleValue) {
                                             var val = new Date(Date.parse(val,"MMM dd yyyy"));
                                             var adult=new Date();

                                             adult.setFullYear(adult.getFullYear() - 18)

                                             return (val<adult);
                                     }
                              </aui:validator>
```

Comment: This is for liferay 7.0